# Is there a way to show the entire simulator screen?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6.3.1

This is what the screen displays on my MacBook. After I updated Xcode, it changed from showing the entire screen of the device to showing part of the screen. I now have to scroll to see everything that would be displayed on the screen.

[image: This is what the screen displays on my MacBook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize simulator using

> command+1
>
> command+2
>
> command+3

if it doesn't fit.. u will need a bigger screen.

Comment: It works :) Thanks you, you just made my life easier!

Answer (score 2):

Bring the simulator app to the front, select the window menu, and choose scale. Pick progressively smaller scales values until the whole simulator fits on your screen. (It should really have a "fit to screen" option, but it doesn't.)